# Postgresql command line utility dosen't start on WSL

Tags: 18.04, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu 18.04; I'm trying to use `postgresql` on my machine, I've taken care of the relevant installations.

But when I enter the command: `sudo -u postgres psql`, it asks for my `sudo` password, and then the cursor blinks on forever.

Can anyone tell me what's happening? and what can I do to fix it?